# WebRTC: can two clients signal eachother at the same time

Tags: javascript, html5-video, webrtc

From reading the webrtc spec, it states that a client can work as the initiator and signal other client (via a signal server). Then the spec says the Client B receives the offer and responds with its signal. Once Client A receives Client B's response signal, the connection is formed.
My question is, can both client A and client B decide to signal each other to form a connection... i.e. does client B have to wait for client A's signal before sending its own signal out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both can initiate the connection and both can listen to it. But one of the connection attempts will fail, so there is just one client that initializes the connection and the other one accepts that.

Comment: So to be clear, one must give a signal offer and another must 'generate' a response signal 'using' the first original signal offer?

Comment: @jonathan every communication needs a handshake first.